# How do I find which CNI plugin is my k8s is using? Where is its config file(s)?

Tags: kubernetes, cni

How can I find easily which CNI plugin is configured and where is the config file associated with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can look into the content in `/etc/cni/net.d` and the binary at `/opt/cni/bin`. If you don't find any of these, you can check kubelet argument `--cni-conf-dir` and `--cni-bin-dir` which will point you to the custom location of your CNI plugin.

Comment: This is the question. How do I check the cni-conf-dir and cni-bin-dir ? I have seen that you can pass them as arguments to kubelet, but what it means "you can check kubelet argument .." ?

Comment: you can find your kubelet arguments [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/#workflow-when-using-kubeadm-init)

Comment: :) still, how does this answer the question: how can I "check kubelet argument --cni-conf-dir and --cni-bin-dir", as this link says to check configmap kubelet-config-1.X, /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf, /var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env etc. , but none of them is giving any cni-bin-dir of cni-conf-dir..

Comment: the link already told you what's the default when none is explicitly specified.

Comment: I think I understand the question, @maiky You need to ssh to your Kubernetes Node, and on the OS itself there should be located kubelet binary, as well as the config files.

Comment: @maiky You can select a running kubelet process and check its `--cni-conf-dir` and `--cni-bin-dirusing` flags with:`ps -ef | grep kubelet`